# Trigger to Populate Lookup via custom field

Tags: apex, trigger

I am trying to write a trigger that will take a user's input into a text field `Orders__c.Site_Code__c` and find the account which has the matching value in `Account.Site_Code__c`.

My trigger passes its test with 100% coverage but when trying to create a new `Orders__c` I get the following error:

> Apex trigger PullOrderSiteAccount caused an unexpected exception,
>   contact your administrator: PullOrderSiteAccount: execution of
>   AfterInsert caused by: System.StringException: Invalid id: 1234:
>   External entry point

Where did I go wrong?

--snip-- 
Working trigger!

```
trigger PullOrderSiteAccount on Orders__c (before insert) {

Set<String> codes = new Set<String>();
for (Orders__c o : trigger.new) codes.add(o.Site_Code__c);

Map<String, Account> siteAccounts = new Map<String, Account>();
for (Account a : [
    SELECT Site_Code__c FROM Account
    WHERE Site_Code__c IN :codes
]) siteAccounts.put(a.Site_Code__c, a);

       for (Orders__c o : Trigger.new)
    {
        Account siteAccount = siteAccounts.get(o.Site_Code__c);
       Id parentId = (siteAccount == null) ? null : siteAccount.Id;
        o.Site_Account__c = parentId;
    }
}
```

updated:

This now works!

Comment: Your test coverage dropped because you don't have any matching records.

Comment: I had alluded to multiple matches at the end of my post, now addressed in further detail.

Comment: please ask your new question as a separate question in SFSE - showing latest code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Site_Code__c` values are `String` type. You need `Map<String, Account>` as your collection type. So:

```
Set<String> codes = new Set<String>();
for (Orders__c order : trigger.new) codes.add(order.Site_Code__c);

Map<String, Account> siteAccounts = new Map<String, Account>();
for (Account record : [
    SELECT Site_Code__c FROM Account
    WHERE Site_Code__c IN :codes
]) siteAccounts.put(record.Site_Code__c, record);

for (Orders__c order : Trigger.new)
{
    Account siteAccount = siteAccounts.get(order.Site_Code__c);
    Id parentId = (siteAccount == null) ? null : siteAccount.Id;
    order.Site_Account__c = parentId;
}
```

The above assumes `Site_Code__c` is a unique field for `Account`. If not, you need to do `Map<Id, List<Account>>` and figure out what to do if there is more than one match.

In more detail, that second scenario would look like:

```
Set<String> codes; // same as above
Map<String, List<Account>> siteAccounts = new Map<String, List<Account>>();
for (Account record : [/*query*/])
{
    if (!siteAccounts.containsKey(record.Site_Code__c))
        siteAccounts.put(record.Site_Code__c, new List<Account>());
    siteAccounts.get(record.Site_Code__c).add(record);
}
for (Orders__c order : trigger.new)
{
    List<Account> matchingAccounts = siteAccounts.get(order.Site_Code__c);
    Id parentId = (matchingAccounts != null && matchingAccounts.size() == 1) ?
        matchingAccounts[0].Id : null;
    order.Site_Account__c = parentId;
}
```

Comment: please see update at bottom of question

Comment: @jatuttle0 You just need to make it `before insert` instead.

Comment: @jatuttle0 You can Use  Before Insert has a DML Event ..if All Accounts are already There ..Atleast DML count will be reduced

Comment: Updating OP with another inquiry

Comment: I have extended the inquiry into a new question http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/122362/trigger-to-lookup-account-based-on-non-unique-text-field

Comment: @jatuttle0 Messed up the syntax, sorry. Fixed it.